# Use of sizeof in declerations

Tags: c

I see declerations of the form

`int *p3 = calloc(4, sizeof *p3);`

in some codes. What are the benefits of using such decleration instead of naming the type like

`int *p3 = calloc(4, sizeof(int));`

Comment: For the first, if you were to change the type of `p3` to something else the `sizeof` wouldn't need to be changed. Less possibility for mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

What if somebody comes along and changes the type of `p3` to be something other than `int`? If they forget to change the repeating mention of `int` in the initialiser, you now have a hard to find bug.

When using `sizeof *p3`, this can’t happen.

Redundancy in code *can* be good; but this isn’t such a case, because the redundancy here is not ensured by the compiler, doesn’t help make the code clearer and serves no other purpose.

Comment: What if the person maintaining the code changes `sizeof *p3` to something other than `*p3`? I don't see why that would be less likely than them changing the declared type. I'm mostly in favour of the `sizeof *p3` style too, but the truth is that arguments for/against it are very subjective. Basically there is no way to protect a programmer from themselves - if the person maintaining the code doesn't know what they are doing, no clever tricks in the world will save them.

Comment: @Lundin I don’t understand in what scenario such a change would occur. What’s more likely is that somebody would change the variable name *in the declaration*. But that usually wouldn’t be a problem: because if they forget to change the `sizeof` expression, the code now fails to compile. — So I disagree with you that this is at all subjective: it trades a fairly common source of error for a very rare one. And that last bit of your comment is something only a C programmer could say, sorry: lots of other languages very effectively protect programmers from themselves.

Comment: @Lundin: The question “What if the person maintaining the code changes `sizeof *p3` to something other than `*p3`?” does not make sense because there is no reason for that to occur other than some completely random typing mistake having nothing to do with the purpose of the code. Once a person adopts the idiom of using `sizeof *p`, where `p` is the thing being assigned, there is no reason to use anything else there. One would not write `sizeof *p[3]` or `sizeof **p` or `sizeof -*p` or anything else. It is like saying we should not use `+` for addition because one might write the wrong operand.

Comment: @Lundin: Re “Basically there is no way to protect a programmer from themselves”: That is false. There are many ways to protect a programmer from themselves. Compiler diagnostic messages often protect a programmer from themselves. Adopting patterns and idioms help protect a programmer from themselves. Clear documentation helps protect a programmer from themselves. Testing helps protect a programmer from themselves. There are a variety of tools that help decrease human errors.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Obvious reasons include: allocating an array instead of a single item,  `sizeof *p3 * n`. Which in turn is easy to screw up in multiple ways, for example `sizeof(*p3 * n)`.

Comment: By protecting the programmer from themselves I mean that whenever you are about to write _any_ C expression, the first thing you do is to ensure you know the type of all variables involved. In case there is any doubt, go check the declaration. If you don't have that habit, you _will_ write bugs. As evident from the millions of SO posts where the poster just drops a snippet without the variable declarations visible - this is a very certain indication of an inexperienced programmer.

Comment: @Lundin: It is certainly no harder to remember to use `sizeof *p3 * n` than to use `sizeof` with the type, so that is not an argument in favor of using `sizeof` with a type. The recommendation “go check the declaration” fails because a key error being guarded against here is a future change to the declaration, not a failure to get the size incorrect at the time the `sizeof` is initially written.